# Do cats avoid water when it is placed near food?

Tags: zoology, water

[This tumblr post](http://liamsen.tumblr.com/post/152733137087/this-actually-has-a-reason-the-most-people) makes the interesting claim that if a cat's water is placed near its food, the cat will consider the water to be unsafe to drink, and that cats will be more inclined to drink it if it is placed in another room.

> The most people put the water bowl next to the food bowl.
>
> This makes the water soiled from the cats point of view!
>
> Why?
>
> Because outdoors water is often contaminated if dead meat is next to it (aka an animal corpse, cat food)
>
> If you put the water bowl next to the cat food the cat is worrying due to it’s instincts that the water could poison it.
>
> That’s the reason why cats often prefered water that’s far away from the food source. Even toilet water seems cleaner and less dangerous for them!
>   Solution?
>
> In our home the water bowl is in another room. While the food bowl is in the kitchen, the water is in the bed room.
>
> Since we changed that our cats are drinking much more water and seemed even healtheir because of that!

Is there any evidence that cats follow this behavior?

Comment: If they're worried about the water being contaminated by the food, shouldn't they also be worried about the food itself?

Comment: I've never seen a cat disdain water for being near food.  However, I have noted a strong preference for colder water.

Comment: @loren-pechtel my ascension evidence directly congrats with your own; I'm very curious is someone can produce any research on this area though.

Comment: How is a tumblr post a notable claim? https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim

Comment: @Daniel From your link: “a claim is notable when a significant number of people believe it is true.” This tumblr post has around 40,000 notes, which I would consider a significant number, even if only a fraction of these notes represent people believing the claim. I usually put the note count on my skeptics post, but it looks like i didn’t this time.